# Tring to get Elements of a form to login in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

Here is my code and it throws exception of : Excepted condition faild to locate element
whats the problem with my code? why driver can't catch html elements.
below after the code, html of the page source on the browser which i can't get from the driver.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
String proxySetting = internalConstant.getAddress() + ":" + internalConstant.getPort();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://driver/chromedriver.exe");
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(); 
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxySetting); 
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxySetting); 

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
        capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy); 

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 

        WebDriver driver = driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get(internalConstant.getUrl());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            logger.info("current url: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 5000).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl\"]")));
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 5000).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_UserName"))).sendKeys(this.internalConstant.getUsername());
            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_password")).sendKeys(this.internalConstant.getPassword());
            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_login")).click();
        catch(TimeoutException e){
                    logger.info("time out exp: " + e.toString());
              
            } 
        finally {
                driver.quit();
            }
```

and here is the html page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOHTMLINDEX" /><title>
    
    Sign In

</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css?rev=ox%2BqLd6WTqhn6d%2FMqf2BMw%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/error.css?rev=nc1850SZNy60qTAeQIRxsA%3D%3D"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js?rev=%2FWTxr8UesytJ8GB%2F5hOwZA%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=b8aG9BSsOzH4Psxrq74Zvc_pIn6eY3of7kBqwPeEeJ8P2XA_lSkmKIifnqd9-IL8CEPfvU6k16J_-_YZ5r2ZblfXiIw1EXtGjGRd08Brd5mgiYh6xWXZ7F3pKzK0NyqjRinRUVml7y_P1P24kyakvpLM7lXNE1ZgeReCzD0S-35tYv52FWCflKfCauowft6K0&amp;t=ffffffff805766b3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=ZaOXZEobVwykPO9g8hq%2F8A%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=8PxrTGbFqBTOmbVOY6PYJ-dNFoq_7BTGppdUkof9uYJ_c_8T-FyZDw8LmG1aWZJM6J49rRIXs-9xGZqJW1umdLd4XQJMFTDswrFyS5pCwqYnvdoprb_5wevdVDkXh4JwfjAHvOpc6RjsFpVFZ5c7AVLop_vMOeT4-uFQQs-n4zUJT_i6nzkqV4BCVM9IJ14Y0&amp;t=ffffffff805766b3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("initstrings.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002finitstrings.js?rev=4Yrxyggg5knao3D48Ii\u00252FWA\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("strings.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002fstrings.js?rev=u\u00252B0KcZWR52dtr8LTlqcZcw\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("strings.js", "initstrings.js");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.init.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsp.init.js?rev=3nSw25FIGbfepznMSgi74A\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.res.resx", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fScriptResx.ashx?culture=en\u00252Dus\u0026name=SP\u00252ERes\u0026rev=yNk\u00252FhRzgBn40LJVP\u00252BqfgdQ\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("sp.ui.dialog.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fsp.ui.dialog.js?rev=0xf6wCIW4E1pN83I9nSIJQ\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("sp.ui.dialog.js", "sp.init.js");RegisterSodDep("sp.ui.dialog.js", "sp.res.resx");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("core.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fcore.js?rev=uA2xjCXmuYM5ARP8g3eTSA\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("core.js", "strings.js");</script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /></head>
<body id="ms-error-body" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();">
    <form method="post" action="default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&amp;Source=%2f" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != &#39;undefined&#39;) {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPBSpWU0tleTozNzIwYjA0My0wZTRiLTRmOTEtOTIwYS1jN2YwNzRjMGQzZWNkn/24vz5ZtU1zojuNDN6GIpggcfrrpaNh3Ux0Gy5TR6w=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=v_PLJBJCpIcKkSvMlNKF0P2DNOij3yylWhnXYr-eXN-HgXXLTGjYbYt4QJ10YYwXDpQAFDr9Ika8viTaiTlLGWHvOxKh0ovxrXhxpv-uBoU1&amp;t=635589543571259667" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var g_presenceEnabled = true;
var g_wsaEnabled = false;
var g_wsaQoSEnabled = false;
var g_wsaQoSDataPoints = [];
var g_wsaLCID = 1033;
var g_wsaListTemplateId = null;
var _fV4UI=true;var _spPageContextInfo = {webServerRelativeUrl: "\u002f", webAbsoluteUrl: "https:\u002f\u002fremittance.bankalbilad.com", siteAbsoluteUrl: "https:\u002f\u002fremittance.bankalbilad.com", serverRequestPath: "\u002f_forms\u002fdefault.aspx", layoutsUrl: "_layouts\u002f15", webTitle: "", webTemplate: "", tenantAppVersion: "none", webLogoUrl: "\u002fSiteAssets\u002fEnjazLogo.png", webLanguage: 1033, currentLanguage: 1033, currentUICultureName: "en-US", currentCultureName: "en-US", clientServerTimeDelta: new Date("2020-11-06T19:02:00.6935939Z") - new Date(), siteClientTag: "14$$15.0.4569.1000", crossDomainPhotosEnabled:false, webUIVersion:15, webPermMasks:{High:0,Low:0}, pagePersonalizationScope:1, alertsEnabled:false, siteServerRelativeUrl: "\u002f", allowSilverlightPrompt:'True',"themedCssFolderUrl" : "/_catalogs/theme/Themed/C7475956","themedImageFileNames" : {"spcommon.png" : "spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=4","ellipsis.11x11x32.png" : "ellipsis.11x11x32-2F01F47D.themedpng?ctag=4","O365BrandSuite.95x30x32.png" : "O365BrandSuite.95x30x32-C212E2FD.themedpng?ctag=4","socialcommon.png" : "socialcommon-6F3394A9.themedpng?ctag=4","spnav.png" : "spnav-230C537D.themedpng?ctag=4"}};var MSOWebPartPageFormName = 'aspnetForm';//]]>
</script>

<script src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=ZaOXZEobVwykPO9g8hq%2F8A%3D%3D" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(DeferWebFormInitCallback) == 'function') DeferWebFormInitCallback();//]]>
</script>

<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=JKZNQQPGwhxlZ02QrerbO_XIcgR4915gcRBEEQOD70Ab7Yez0BwpZBhk-oHFF4AlJD79wCvy3oNRCS9mrby8Yghy6toAP1me9FsA6E5vVig1&amp;t=635589543571259667" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="2EB18009" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAQXglRNYXr74m4KXXhr5Tg7D3gNq6qp/JTilQw5ZNkpfe4vJyKPNbAHwGois4u5nam1l6dqP2Wbh/cJ6mTdRfbZbWeydvlh6wRzCcTcUOMRXZNxPizwWTG/l3GXqkCZTi4=" />
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager', 'aspnetForm', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>

    <div id="ms-error-header" class="ms-pr">
        <h1 class="ms-core-pageTitle">
            
        </h1>
        <div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ms-error">
        <div id="ms-error-top">
            
        </div>
        <div id="ms-error-content">
            <div id="ms-error-error-content">
                <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">
    
                    

<style>
body{font-family:tahoma !important;font-size:13px !important;}
.login_holder{width:600px;height:450px;background:#eaeaea;margin:40px auto 0 auto;border:1px solid #eaeaea;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);}
.logo_holder{width:100%;background:#fff;border-bottom:2px solid #fcb034;padding:10px 0}
.login_holder p{padding:10px;color:#455560}
.user_div, .pass_div{padding:10px !important;}
.user_div label, .pass_div label{width:120px !important;color:#999 !important;display:inline-block !important;font-weight:bold !important;text-align:right !important;padding:10px !important;}
.text_in{width:320px !important;height:35px !important;border:1px solid #CCC !important;padding:0 10px !important;color:#666 !important;font-size:17px !important;}
.enter_btn{cursor:pointer !important;float:left !important;margin:15px 0 0 158px !important;width:150px !important;height:40px !important;background:#455560 !important;border:1px solid #455560 !important;color:#fff !important;}
.enter_btn:hover{background:#ef4035;border:1px solid #333;}
.login_error{color:#c60f13;font-weight:bold}
.clear{clear:both;float:none}
</style>


 <div class="login_holder">
    <div class="logo_holder">
        <img src="/_layouts/Remittance.WebApp/images/EnjazLogo.png"" alt="" />
    </div>
 <p id="SslWarning" style="color:red;display:none">
 Warning: this page is not encrypted for secure communication. User names, passwords, and any other information will be sent in clear text. For more information, contact your administrator.
 </p>
  <script language="javascript" >
    if (document.location.protocol != 'https:')
    {
        var SslWarning = document.getElementById('SslWarning');
        SslWarning.style.display = '';
    }
  </script>

 <table id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="user_div">
                <label>User name:</label>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$signInControl$UserName" type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_UserName" class="text_in" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="pass_div">
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$signInControl$password" type="password" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_password" class="text_in" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$signInControl$login" value="Sign In" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_login" class="enter_btn" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div style="padding:10px;"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_FailureText" class="login_error"></span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>

                
</div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var _fV4UI = true;WebForm_AutoFocus('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl');//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the page you are using or its HTML code? Otherwise it's hard to tell where the problem lies.

Comment: I added the html

Comment: use presenceOfElement instead of clickable for the input fields...  Also the 5 second polling period is a little weird.  I would remove that... just use WebDriverWait(driver, 20).  You're also mixing Implicit and Explicit waits.  Don't do that.  Implicit waits are global, so if you want to use that, remove all your explicit ones.  (otherwise you'll have some dueling sleep loops)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no need to wait for the visibility of the table fist and then wait for the visibillity of the box to send the username so first of all
remove this line:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 5000).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl\"]")));
```

Use this xpath for the usernamebox :

```
//input[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_UserName']
```

Try this xpath for the passwordbox :

```
  //input[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_signInControl_password']
```

From my experience `By.xpath` is better than `By.id`

Comment: you'r right no need to wait for the table, but it didnot work too. so I used the same code in python and it worked.